# Ionic service worker send OPTIONS for GET

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, cors, service-worker

I'm currently working with Ionic to get data from an API. Although it's been working for the last days, I don't know how it stopped working.

I am using `@angular/http` to make my requests. When not using any headers, my request goes to `GET` Method, and doesn't work because I need an Authorization token.

But, if I had Headers via:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', this.bearerToken);            
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

It doesn't work either. The request goes to `OPTIONS` Method, and is returning:

```
Unauthorized header authorization
```

Is there anything I can do on Ionic to fix this, or should I warn the API developers in order to make them do some changes?

Edit: The API developers are using Symfony and Nelmio CORS Bundle to handle these settings

```
nelmio_cors:
   defaults:
       origin_regex: true
       allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
       allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
       allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
       max_age: 3600
   paths:
       '^/': ~
```

As @Moshe mentionned, their configuration should contain some `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, and they do apparently..

Comment: can you share your http request implementation?

Comment: You mean this ? `const data = this.http.get(dataUrl, options).map(data => data.json());`

Comment: Basically you need to ask the API developer to provide you with details of how they want YOU to query data from them. Like end point description (what parameters, what headers they expect) - then you can build your implementation based on that. If you could update the question with their response - I can help with your implementation

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to HTTP Headers (such as Authorization) the client sends an `OPTIONS` request in order to check if the headers are accepted by server first. I've had a similar issue with my client-server relationship. You must enable authorization in Access-Control-Allow-Headers in your server.

Example:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization');
```

Comment: Hey how can you assume its CORS issue if the question doesn't provide context for that? there are not errors that says that as far as I understand here? do I miss something? The question hints that there are errors relating to auth - which means there is no rejection based on CORS. So I wonder

Comment: `Unauthorized header authorization` was my error as well. I fixed it with CORS. Since the header is unauthorized, it means the server needs to "authorize" it. Additionally, he is able to make a `GET` request without the headers, and adding it causes the trouble. (the fact that it goes to `OPTIONS` is just standard HTTP stuff. With an `Authorization` header I've experienced the "two requests:" One `OPTIONS` followed by one `GET.` The fact that OP only sees `OPTIONS` means that the header was rejected by the server

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help :)

Comment: I've edited my question with configuration parameters

Comment: try allow_origin: ['*']